# Dialogflow работа бота в зависимости от времени суток

Tags: dialogflow

Как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал только в определенно заданное время суток?

Comment: Введите условие, которое проверяет текущее время и сравнивает его с заданным диапазоном. По-моему, это совсем не сложная проверка.

Comment: Я понимаю как это сделать в обычном листинге, но так как я не имел вообще никакого опыта с  dialogflow, не могли бы вы подсказать, где именно там надо прописать условие?